# linux path in fstream

Tags: c++, linux, file-io

i try to create a new file and save it in a subdirectory of the current folder ON LINUX

the path(convert) should look something like markus/123456 where markus is an (existing) subdirectory and 123456 is the non existing file

the strange thing is: it works when i dont use a subdirectory to say it short:

"123456"          works and makes a file in the current directory

"markus/123456"   dont works and does nothing at all...

```
ofstream handle;
string convert = "1234";
convert=name +"/"+ convert;
cout << convert<< endl;
handle.open(convert.c_str(),ios::out); // dont works with subdirectory in string
handle<<message;
handle.close();
```

NOTICE: I am using linux not windows. I need a solution for linux (3.0.0-12-generic-pae).

EDIT:
Thx to one of the commends i found out its proberply a right problem. I post the code how i created the folder:

```
user::user(string aaa)
{
    name=aaa;
    mkdir(name.c_str(),0600);

}
```

NOTICE: I also tried it with 0666 without sucess. Still dont know how to do it right

Comment: What output does it produce? What error do you get?

Comment: Please reduce your program to a minimal, complete, compilable sample program. In the process you may very well find the problem yourself. If you don't, the complete program will allow us to find the problem much more quickly. See http://sscce.org for more info.

Comment: it does not produce any output on the terminal. the ofstream just failes to open. If i use `handle.isopen();` after it saies no.
if i dont use the path it just succeds

Comment: So it should work. Which suggests you are either spelling it incorrectly, running it from the wrong directory (as the path will be relative from the current working directory (assuming the first char is not '/')) or do not have write permission to the directory. Have you checked the current working directory? Try `getcwd()` see what it outputs.

Comment: thanks for the hint! Its an right problem. I deleted the directory and created it manually. After that i was able to write. `mkdir(name.c_str(),0600);` is the command how the directory was created before. `name` is the part of the class and the same as in my example before. Also the part cant be different because Im createing directory and file(on "123456" example) in the same directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mkdir(name.c_str(),0600);
```

This is wrong. Try

```
mkdir(name.c_str(), 0700);
```